# Bootstrap 4 grid issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having some problems of respecting the grid of bootstrap 4. I have a content of `col-sm-9` and a right sidebar of `col-sm-3 float-right`. But the sidebar does not start from the top, but start just after the end of `col-sm-9`. I would like to align both the column.

Here is how the page it is looking: [image: Boostrap wrong grid] 
Here you can inspect the code of the page: [Code](http://new.wearegoingsolo.com/tracks/paperwhite-human-nature)

This is basically my html:

```
<section class="row clearfix" ng-cloak>
<div class="content-top no-gutters">
<div style="background-image: url({{post.better_featured_image.source_url}});" class="content-tracks-image">
</div>
    <div class="content-featured-image">
            <img>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="gs-track col-sm-9"><!--start player-->      
<!---player--->
</div><!-- close player -->
<div class="col-sm-9 bg-white pt-3 pb-3" ng-cloak><!-- start content-->
<!--content->
</div><!-- close content -->
<div class="col-sm-3 float-right pt-3"><!-- start sidebar -->
<!-- sidebar -->
</div><!-- close sidebar -->

</section>
```

I was able to align the sidebar to the content but I had to move the sidebar box before the player, and I don't want to have this behaviour.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious or flagged by filter systems; users may not be able to visit them. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Why downvoted? I've fixed my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was difficult working with your supplied link since when I tried to run the HTML I would not get the same content. But upon manually putting in my own content and trying to recreated I found that using bootstraps ROW on a container div worked.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-9">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">SIDEBAR</div>
</div>
```

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: You were right, I had to add another row, I've fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I set this as valid, but what was wrong with my question? Someone downvoted me

Comment: @GoingSolo Welcome to Stack Oveflow. People get excited when they play moderator here and downvote anything which isn't perfect in their eyes. Probably because your issue was hard to recreate. I personally don't think someone's lack of interest to put extra effort in solving a question justifies a downvote.